# Is it easy to get an Uber in Colombo?

Tags: taxis, sri-lanka, uber, colombo

How easy is it to get an Uber in Colombo, especially from the airport into the city? Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Uber is in Sri Lanka and so are alternatives. Why wouldn't there be any taxis at an airport? There is a discussion of taxi services in Colombo [here](https://www.readme.lk/exploring-sri-lanka-uber-pickme-taxiyak/).

Comment: As a Sri Lankan I must say that the normal taxis near airports charge more. It is like scam. It is better to use Uber or Pickme (Alternative for Uber) for travelling since they have a fixed cheap price for everyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anecdote here, as its usually much helpful in this case.

I had took uber from Airport to city when I visited Colombo. It is easy to get. You can get a sim card from airport for cheap with your passport and it will be activated immediately (In case you don't have international roaming). You can call uber afterwards. It should be way cheaper than taxis.

Date: October 2017

Answer (score 1):

As per [Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/map/Colombo-Airport-CMB/Colombo) you actually have quite a few options, including Uber:

- depending on the airport, you could fly to the closer airport first. Probably can ignore this option.
- taxi
- drive (or hitch?) if renting
- town car
- Uber

each with an estimate of pricing. You can choose which is best for you